ComposeView doesn't always refresh when composable content recomposes
I am absolutely baffled by this: I want to show a composable miniplayer in a ComposeView (in the layout.xml of a Fragment) as the rest of the screen (apart from one other ComposeView) is still in xml. The miniplayer recomposes just fine when state changes but this isn't always reflected on screen as sometimes the view doesn't update when state changes but if I run the app again it might just work as expected (or not).
What I have tried:

Verifying the state does indeed update as expected (it does)
Verifying the composable recomposes (it does and even when the state updates the UI doesn't always change but it does recompose)
Verifying the actual song chosen does not cause this issue (same song/data sometimes works and most of the times doesn't work so it's unrelated)
Verifying if the same composable works in a fully composable screen (it does)
Updating the compose BOM to the latest version (was using 2024.05.00 and now 2024.08.00)
Updating Android Studio
Fiddling with the view composition strategy of the ComposeView
Using observeAsState() instead of observeAsStateWithLifecycle()

Some code:
Part of the XML layout containing the ComposeView

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/miniPlayerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

How I put the composable content in the ComposeView
    ui.miniPlayerView.setContent {
        AppTheme {
            MiniAudioPlayer()
        }
    }

The composable
private const val MINIMUM_DRAG_AMOUNT = -100f

@Composable
fun MiniAudioPlayer(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    playerHandler: PlayerHandler = koinInject()
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val state by playerHandler.miniPlayerState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    val progress by remember { derivedStateOf { state.progress } }
    val showPlayer by remember { derivedStateOf { state.showPlayer } }
    val isPlaying by remember { derivedStateOf { state.isPlaying } }
    val title by remember { derivedStateOf { state.title } }
    val thumbnailUrl by remember { derivedStateOf { state.thumbnailUrl } }
    var totalDragAmount by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    if (showPlayer) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .clickable(interactionSource = interactionSource, indication = null) { context.openAudioPlayer() }
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectVerticalDragGestures(
                        onDragStart = { totalDragAmount = 0f },
                    ) { _, dragAmount ->
                        totalDragAmount += dragAmount
                        if (totalDragAmount < MINIMUM_DRAG_AMOUNT) context.openAudioPlayer()
                    }
                }
                .background(color = LocalCustomColors.current.background)
                .background(color = colorResource(R.color.miniplayer_background))
                .padding(16.dp),
        ) {
            MMImage(
                url = thumbnailUrl,
                size = DpSize(54.dp, 54.dp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(54.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(12.dp))
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                Header5Text(
                    text = title,
                    maxLines = 1
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                MMProgressBar(progress = { progress })
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(18.dp))
            MMIcon(
                drawableId = if (isPlaying) R.drawable.ic_miniplayer_pause_button else R.drawable.ic_miniplayer_play_button,
                size = 34.dp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable(interactionSource = interactionSource, indication = null) {
                        playerHandler.togglePlayState()
                    }
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            )
        }
    }
}

How I update the values in the ViewModel (PlayerHandler class)
private val _miniPlayerState = MutableStateFlow(MiniPlayerUiState())
val miniPlayerState = _miniPlayerState.asStateFlow()

_miniPlayerState.update { it.copy(progress = progress / 100f) }

The state
data class MiniPlayerUiState(
    val showPlayer: Boolean = false,
    val isPlaying: Boolean = false,
    val progress: Float = 0f,
    val title: String = "",
    val thumbnailUrl: String? = null
)


Remove all your uses of derivedStateOf as they are not doing what you appear to expect. It is pointless to use derivedStateOf for non-state objects such as the value sent by miniPlayerState. You are caching a value that will not be invalidated because the expression doesn't read any snapshot state.

@chuckj I must admit that this use of derivedStateOf has always seemed a bit dodgy and tedious but this what makes sure I don't get any unnecessary recompositions and I haven't found a better way. If I remove the derivedStateOf usages any change to the base state object would trigger every composable that uses any of those values to recompose. If music is playing the viewmodel updates the miniplayer state object every second because of the progress bar state and because derivedStateOf the other state values like isPlaying only update when that value is changed. I added my VM and state code.

The example you give above is unaffected by derivedStateOf. For example, the showPlayer field, if the field is not backed by a mutableStateOf, the value of val showPlayer will never change even if state.showPlayer does. Also, if it is backed by a mutableStateOf then wrapping it in a derivedStateOf is just adding overhead for with no benefit. derivedStateOf() will only reevaluate if one of the state objects it reads changes. This means either MiniAudioPlayer() will not recompose enough or it will recompose the same number of times without derivedStateOf.

Apologies for the late reply but I just wasn't sure how to answer this. You mention derivedStateOf() will only reevaluate if one of the state objects it reads changes and that is the case in my example. The state object changes and therefore derivedStateOf() will reevaluate. I have verified this with logs and the recomposition count in AS. I just found out the issue has been caused by enabling strong skipping mode in the compose options. If I remove that line everything works perfectly again and each composable recomposes when it's corresponding derived state changes.

Turns out this issue was caused by having strong skipping mode enabled in the compose compiler options... I guess ComposeViews are not (yet?) compatible with strong skipping mode.
composeCompiler {
    enableStrongSkippingMode = true

    ...
}

